# How to pass looping through multidimentional array into function

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Hi  Currently i am working with some multidimentional array operations with looping.

Actually i have to pass multidimentional array to function and in that function i need whole array data.

But issue here is i am getting only single item of array not all items of  array in function.

**Below the code which i have try :**

```
foreach($sp_data as $sp_product_data) // this loop is for another purpose
                {

                  $sp_product_details = (array)$sp_product_data;
                  $product_links = array(array(
                  'sku' => $gp_sku,
                  'link_type' => 'associated',
                  'linked_product_sku' => $sp_product_details['sku'], 
                  'linked_product_type' => 'simple',
                  'position' => '1',    
                  )
                ); 
             echo "<pre>";
            print_r(product_links); //When i am printing the data its shows me all array items

        $this->testproduct($product_links); // but when i am pass the data to function and in that function when i displayed data its gives only first array item
                }
```

**My function :**

```
function testproduct($product_links)
{
echo "<pre>";
print_r($product_links);
}
```

**In function i am getting only first item of array. Please  help what i am missing**

Comment: try using array_push before calling the testproduct function

Comment: @Manthan Can you please update your post with expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing whole array you have to do this
Use this format

```
$product_links[]=array(
              'sku' => $gp_sku,
              'link_type' => 'associated',
              'linked_product_sku' => $sp_product_details['sku'], 
              'linked_product_type' => 'simple',
              'position' => '1',    
                );
}#end of foreach loop
#now call the testproduct function. THis line must be outside the loop

$this->testproduct($product_links);
```

Comment: Also call that "testproduct" outside the loop

Comment: Thanks its works like charm !! short and simple . Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) for this
So the code should be like this

```
$custom_product_data = array();
foreach($sp_data as $sp_product_data) {
  $sp_product_details = (array)$sp_product_data;
  $product_links = array(
      'sku' => $gp_sku,
      'link_type' => 'associated',
      'linked_product_sku' => $sp_product_details['sku'], 
      'linked_product_type' => 'simple',
      'position' => '1',    
  ); 

    if( is_array($product_links) ) {
      array_push($custom_product_data, $product_links);
    }
  }

  $this->testproduct($custom_product_data);
```

**NOTE**

Don't forget to use testproduct function outside the loop. Otherwise it will not give you result.